# Batch script not doing anything when execute from remote machine using ssh

Tags: batch-file, ssh, remote-access

i'm having a problem while executing batch script from linux machine.

Scenario:
I've a windows machine installed server2008, I need to automate some windows task that executes from linux machine. I've installed cygwin software on windows VM and create a batch script that is running fine from cygwin terminal. i.e cd ~/;./script.bat

Problem:
When I execute the same script from linux machine using ssh it seems works fine and print script executed successfully but when I checked that the task from windows it did nothing.

cat script.bat

```
@echo off

set sourcePasswd=%1
set destinationPasswd=%2
set destinationProjectName=%3
set user=%4
set xmlPath=C:\cygwin\home\%user%\Duplicate.xml

ECHO Start : Duplication project source for %destinationProjectName%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MySoftware\Duplicate.EXE" -f %xmlPath% -sp        %sourcePasswd% -dp %destinationPasswd% -sup -md -dn %destinationProjectName%
ECHO Finish : Duplication project source for %destinationProjectName%
```

Comment: Issue has been resolved by follow the instructions on following link.

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-07/msg00598.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Leopard hasn't been back since he posted the question or  the link to the answer, so I'll be the Point Pimpette tonight and fill in the blank.

The answer below is from the link:
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-07/msg00598.html

It was fixed after doing the following setup :

1. Open control panel=> Administrative Tools=>Computer
   Management=>Services
2. lookup the sshd service, right
   click=>properties=>log on, and check the checkbox for Allow service
   to interact with desktop
3. restart the service.

thanks
Saravana